# How do I connect to mongodb on MacOS after adding configurations for replica set?

Tags: mongodb

I want to tail mongo collection's documents and in order to do so, I need to activate the oplog. Oplog requires some extra configuration in the mongod.conf file and these configurations are not letting mongo connected.

I tried to look into questions pertaining to tailing mongodb, setting conf file but none could address my need of connecting to mongodb after setting replciaset configs.

My conf file, location of which is `/usr/local/etc/mongod.conf` is:

```
systemLog:
  destination: file
  path: /usr/local/var/log/mongodb/mongo.log
  logAppend: true
storage:
  dbPath: /usr/local/var/mongodb
net:
  bindIp: 127.0.0.1
replSet=rs0
oplogSize=1024
```

I am not getting anything in logs, `brew services list` command also shows the following:

```
mongodb   started aviralsrivastava /Users/aviralsrivastava/Library/LaunchAgents/homebrew.mxcl.mongodb.plist
```

Although, when rs0 is set, the `started` signal is yellow in color, with the last two lines commented, its green.

I expect `mongodb` to get connected, mongo shell to start but all I get is connection refused. If I comment the last two lines, mongo gets connected. And yes, I did restart `mongodb` via `brew services restart mongodb` each time I changed the config file.

Following is the error when I try to connect via command `mongodb`:

```
➜  etc mongo
MongoDB shell version v4.0.3
connecting to: mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017
2019-04-27T08:53:31.350+0530 E QUERY    [js] Error: couldn't connect to server 127.0.0.1:27017, connection attempt failed: SocketException: Error connecting to 127.0.0.1:27017 :: caused by :: Connection refused :
connect@src/mongo/shell/mongo.js:257:13
@(connect):1:6
exception: connect failed
```

Answer (score 0):

`mongod --config path/to/config-file-portx --replSet rsName`

connect:
`mongo --port xxx`
config:

```
config: 
rs.initialize();
rs.add(host:port-y);
rs.status()
```

connect with replica:

```
mongo "mongodb://host1,host2,host3/myDB?replicaSet=rsName"
```

Comment: It didn't work. For the first command that you posted:
```➜  etc mongod --config mongod.conf --replSet rs0
Error parsing YAML config file: yaml-cpp: error at line 10, column 1: end of map not found
try 'mongod --help' for more information
```

My mongod.conf file is pasted in the question